# How to pass a value from c# to refcursor parameter in oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, odp.net

Can you help me to pass a value from C# to refCursor type. I tried to send dataTable as shown in below link, but its not working.
[Pass datatable to refcursor of Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249670/pass-datatable-to-refcursor-of-oracle-stored-procedure)

Stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE PROC_INS(  P_USERID IN VARCHAR2,
                     P_ATTACH_LIST IN SYS_REFCURSOR,
                     P_out      OUT NUMBER,
                     P_msg     OUT VARCHAR2) AS

V_BRS_USERID         VARCHAR2(50);
V_ATTACHMENT_TYPE_ID BRS_USER_ATTACHMENT.ATTACHMENT_TYPE_ID%TYPE;
V_FILE_NAME          BRS_USER_ATTACHMENT.FILE_NAME%TYPE;
V_FILE_SIZE          BRS_USER_ATTACHMENT.FILE_SIZE%TYPE;
V_FILE_DESCR         BRS_USER_ATTACHMENT.FILE_DESCR%TYPE; 

BEGIN 
LOOP 
FETCH P_ATTACH_LIST INTO V_BRS_USERID, V_ATTACHMENT_TYPE_ID,V_FILE_NAME, V_FILE_SIZE,   V_FILE_DESCR; 
EXIT WHEN P_ATTACH_LIST%NOTFOUND; 
INSERT INTO USER_ATTACHMENT VALUES
        (SEQ_RER_EMP_REP_ID.NEXTVAL,
          V_BRS_USERID,
          V_ATTACHMENT_TYPE_ID,
          V_FILE_NAME,
          V_FILE_SIZE,
          V_FILE_DESCR,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          0,
          0,
          'A',
          P_USERID,
          SYSDATE,
          NULL,
          NULL
        );

END LOOP; 

CLOSE P_ATTACH_LIST;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 ROLLBACK; -- Transaction mgmt
 p_out := 2;
 p_msg := sqlerrm;

  END PROC_REG_INS_ATTACH;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass datatable to refcursor of Oracle stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249670/pass-datatable-to-refcursor-of-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate post by this user. See [Pass datatable to refcursor of Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249670/pass-datatable-to-refcursor-of-oracle-stored-procedure)

You can't bind a DataTable to a Ref Cursor. You'll need to pass in another ref cursor and you can only get that as the output of a stored procedure/function, or a query against a table in an anonymous block... perhaps you can create a wrapper stored procedure that uses different data types, such as associative arrays.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jan/o16odpnet-087852.html

Answer (score -2):

Use [OracleCommand](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm) i [OracleParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleParameterClass.htm) classes. Notice ParameterDirection property of OracleParameter.

Here is the example from my code, I am calling `web_shop_interface.kreiraj_mp_racun` stored procedure, and setting params for it:

```
var fnRac = new OracleCommand();
fnRac.Connection = conn;
fnRac.CommandText = "web_shop_interface.kreiraj_mp_racun";
fnRac.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var ret = new OracleParameter("ret", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
ret.Size = 4096;
fnRac.Parameters.Add(ret);

var p1 = new OracleParameter("did", OracleDbType.Decimal);
p1.Value = 15m;
p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
fnRac.Parameters.Add(p1);

var p2 = new OracleParameter("prn", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
p2.Value = "Invoice 15";
p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
fnRac.Parameters.Add(p2);

fnRac.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: In your stored procedure, there is no input parameter of type RefCursor. My stored procedure has input parameter of type RefCursor. My problem is how to send a value to RefCursor parameter from C# code.

Comment: see OracleParameter documentation, you have to set OracleDbType parameter to OracleDbType.RefCursor.